# Python separating images and text from MS office files

Tags: python, file

Is there a way to separate the text and images from MS Office files like word, excel, ppt etc.
and getting the position of the image in a document( where the image starts in the document between text)?

The application needs to be developed for Linux box.

Please suggest.

Comment: If you're stuck with 97-2003 files it will be much, *much* harder than if you can use 2007 files which are ZIPs (document as XML plus the other files).

Comment: I don't think that there is a library out there that can do this, mostly because [the Office file formats are rather complicated](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html). To extract the images, you can save the file as a .docx/.xlsx file, rename it to `*.zip` and find the images inside the zip archive.

Comment: You might have another fighting chance when you save the document as RTF, that way it's at least a "readable" format; perhaps you can find the position of the images there.

Comment: @Tim I have googled a bit and could not find a library in python to do so. I understand that there can be issues because of file formats, especially when these MS office files have to be processed in the linux environment where we would not be able to use windows specific modules of python as well.

Comment: Is there any hint to start with?

Comment: rtf may work in case of doc but I guess if not work with excel, ppt and other formats?

Comment: Have you read the article I linked to in my first comment? That should give you an idea what you're up against and what options you have.

Comment: How about saving as XML?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the Python UNO bindings for OpenOffice - wiki at http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Python - this should let you open and work with MSOffice docs on linux.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish - a new way to HTML-ize Office docs?